# How do I change the values of variables inside functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm trying to do more OOP in Javascript.
One thing i can't figure out is how can i modify a variable inside an object from another function?

Here's how I tried to do it:

```
function Ball(){
    radius = 5;
    Y = 20;
    X = 25; // The value i would like to change.
    ctx.arc(this.X, this.Y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#00ff00';
    ctx.fill();
}

function draw(){
    Player();
    Ball();
}

function update(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 400);
    draw();
    Ball.X++;  // This is where i want to modify the value.

}
```

So far I've only been able to do it if I define X as a global variable, but I dont want to do that since there are other X and Y values.

So how would i access the variable from outside the function?

**EDIT:**
The solution provided by "nnnnnn" worked to an extent, it changes the X value but I ran into another problem.
My clearRect doesnt clear the animation, so instead of a ball it draws a line that just grows.

This is what the code looks like right now:

```
function Ball(){
    this.radius = 5;
    this.Y = 20;
    this.X = 25;
    this.draw = function() {
       ctx.arc(this.X, this.Y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
       ctx.fillStyle = '#00ff00';
       ctx.fill();
    };
}

var ball = new Ball();

function draw(){
    Player();
    ball.draw();
}


function update(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 400);
    draw();
    ball.X++;
}
```

I have tried moving it around, placing it both in the draw() and ball.draw() functions, but still getting the same result, I also tried doing a fillRect instead of clear but it didnt help.
Anyone able to see whats wrong?

Comment: no bad feelings, but I'd rather learn to walk before running. Your code looks not very ambitious. Your're not dealing with an instance/object, you're just having variables (not even local ones) in a function there.

Comment: yeah they used to be this.X and this.Y etc but since those are local i tried to make em globally changeable :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"So far I've only been able to do it if I define X as a global variable"*

Actually your variables `radius`, `X` and `Y` variables *are* all global variables. For them to be properties of an object they need to be set as follows:

```
someObject.radius = 5;
// OR
someObject["radius"] = 5;
```

They're not local variables within the `Ball()` function because they're not declared with `var` - any variables that you assign a value to without declaring them with `var` automatically become global.

Your `Ball()` function is not creating an object when you call it - in order for it to do so  you need to use `new`:

```
var ball = new Ball();
```

If you call it with `new` then JS automatically creates a new *instance* of `Ball` and within the function `this` refers to that new instance. So the function should say:

```
function Ball(){
    this.radius = 5;
    this.Y = 20;
    this.X = 25; // The value i would like to change.
    ctx.arc(this.X, this.Y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#00ff00';
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Then you can access and change properties as follows:

```
var ball = new Ball();
alert(ball.X); // 25
ball.X++;
```

However that doesn't really fit with the way you've structured your code because you're trying to call `Ball()` to make it draw itself. You probably want something more like this:

```
function Ball(){
    this.radius = 5;
    this.Y = 20;
    this.X = 25;
    this.draw = function() {
       ctx.arc(this.X, this.Y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
       ctx.fillStyle = '#00ff00';
       ctx.fill();
    };
}

var ball = new Ball();

function draw(){
    Player();
    ball.draw();
}

function update(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 400);
    draw();
    ball.X++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked :). I tried something similar earlier but couldnt get it to run. I still get one problem though, the clearRect doesnt work, so instead of a 5 radius ball it draws a line that just gets longer and longer.

Where should I put my clearRect?

Comment: I'm not sure - I would think if you always call `.clearRect()` just before `draw()` within the `update()` function that should do it. Can you post a demo to http://jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Ball function, use `this.X = 25;`.  Then, when you instantiate Ball, you can do

```
var ball = new Ball();
ball.X++;
```

More info here: [OOP in JS, Part 1 : Public/Private Variables and Methods](http://phrogz.net/JS/Classes/OOPinJS.html).

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of type Ball, use its reference to modify instance variables.

```
function update(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 400);
    draw();
    var objBall = new Ball();
    objBall.X++
}
```

Comment: This requires a `this.X = 25;` in `Ball`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that. First you can use the contructor way by adding `this` keyword at the front of the variable you want to use outside. Like this:

```
function Ball(){
  this.radius = 5;
  this.Y = 20;
  this.X = 25; // The way you wanted.

  ctx.arc(this.X, this.Y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#00ff00';
  ctx.fill();
}

//call it like this 
Ball.X;
Ball.Y;
Ball.radius;

//or inside an assigned variable which is instantiated with 'new' keyword:
var myVar = new Ball(); 
myVar.X;
myVar.Y;
myVar.radius;
```

or use object notation, like this:

```
var Ball = {
  radius: 5,
  Y: 20,
  X: 25,

  someFunction: function() {
    //Even in here use 'this' to refer to any property of the object 'Ball', like this:
    var product = this.radius * this.X;

    return product + this.Y
  }

};

//call it also this way
Ball.X;

//or
Ball.radius;

//or
Ball.someFunction();
```

Now use it anywhere:

```
function update(){
  //Now you can use it anywhere
  var smallBall = new Ball();
  smallBall.X++;
}
```

So if you want to make a property to belong to an object use `this` in a constructor or just use the object notation method. Your choice of techniques depends on what you want to do in your project.
Also if you want to hide any property (i.e variables, function, etc) in an object, use the `var` keyword so that the property won't be global.